# C++ Windows Files Search yielding

Tags: c++, windows, yield, file-search

I need two functions:

- Search for a file by file name
- Search for a file by content

For that I obviously need to iterate through all files.
I have the following code which works just fine and *prints* all the files recursivly.

I want to it to *yield* a file each time it is called, or something similar.

```
void FindFile(const std::wstring &directory)
{
    std::wstring tmp = directory + L"\\*";
    WIN32_FIND_DATAW file;
    HANDLE search_handle = FindFirstFileW(tmp.c_str(), &file);
    if (search_handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::vector<std::wstring> directories;

        do
        {
            if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
            {
                if ((!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L".")) || (!lstrcmpW(file.cFileName, L"..")))
                    continue;
            }

            tmp = directory + L"\\" + std::wstring(file.cFileName);
            std::wcout << tmp << std::endl;

            if (file.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
                directories.push_back(tmp);
        }
        while (FindNextFileW(search_handle, &file));

        FindClose(search_handle);

        for(std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator iter = directories.begin(), end = directories.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
            FindFile(*iter);
    }
}
```

The problem is - I also need to search for a file by file content, and for that I need to copy that code and modify it a little which will result in code duplication - which is bad.

I want to have a function that yields file names under a directory and then the two other functions will be able to use it:

- The file name function will compare the file name
- The file content function will read the file and search for the provided content

I couldn't find any good information on how to achieve that in C++ (it seems easy in Python, for example)

Comment: [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) might make your life easier otherwise you probably need to move `FindFile` into a class and keep hold of the `search_handle` between calls

Comment: One is more difficult than the other. For different criteria simply provide a `std::function<bool(const std::wstring&)>` (`#include <functional>`) which evaluates, if a file name matches the criterion. For the other you probably need to create a object containing the current state of the iteration. This object would contain a stack containing info about the directory currently searched.

Comment: I was looking for a simple solution but according to your answers it seems there isn't one. I think I will try a different approach then.